# how use variable from iframe to another iframe in different domain?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I see this video when the minute 1:49 the user click a button of the color of  iframe 2 and  change the iframe 1

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nSjykKMi8g

what type of technique could i use for get this

please help me

Comment: Those iframe's are on the same domain...

Comment: what mean different domain ?

Answer (score 1):

The frames can't communicate directly but you can communicate via a server you control. This server can be on any domain.

You can push events using AJAX and receive events using [server-sent-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events). Make sure you're dealing with the cross domain requests appropriately by implementing CORS on the server.